# Как в aiogram получить результат опроса, созданного пользователем

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Нужно получать результаты опросов, созданных в группе пользователями. На данный момент имеется следующий код:

```
@rt.message(Command("poll"))
async def poll(msg: Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_poll(
        chat_id=msg.chat.id,
        question='Example question',
        options=['1', '2'],
        type='regular',
        is_anonymous=False,
        allows_multiple_answers=True
        )


@rt.poll_answer()
async def poll_res(pa: PollAnswer):
    print(pa.option_ids, pa.user.id)
```

И он работает, как надо, но только в том случае, если опрос создан ботом, в данном случае командой /poll, а когда опрос создается пользователем, хендлер не обрабатывает ответы на этот опрос.